# How to define a variable which implement the interface in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I hope to define a variable `mAction` which implement the interface `MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener` .

But Code A isn't correct, how can I fix it?

**Code A**

```
  val mAction: MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener{
        mr, what, extra ->
           if (what == MediaRecorder.MEDIA_RECORDER_INFO_MAX_DURATION_REACHED) {
               //ToDo
          }
    }
```

**Added Content:**

**Code B**

```
val mAction = object: MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener{
         override fun onInfo(mr: MediaRecorder?, what: Int, extra: Int) {
              if (what == MediaRecorder.MEDIA_RECORDER_INFO_MAX_DURATION_REACHED) {
                       
              }
          }
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are simply missing an `=` instead of `:`.

```
val mAction = MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener{
        mr, what, extra ->
           if (what == MediaRecorder.MEDIA_RECORDER_INFO_MAX_DURATION_REACHED) {
               //ToDo
          }
    }
```

You can’t define a property without `=` unless you are defining a custom getter or using a property delegate.

Answer (score 0):

```
  val mAction = MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener{
        mr, what, extra ->
           if (what == MediaRecorder.MEDIA_RECORDER_INFO_MAX_DURATION_REACHED) {
               //ToDo
          }
    }
```

you can achieve this by doing something like this

Comment: Thanks! your code is not correct, Code B in my question is correct.

Comment: yeah thanks updated wrong answer to right answer